# Servlet Context Listener preventing webapp from loading

Tags: servlets, tomcat7, java-ee-6, servletcontextlistener, servlet-listeners

I am creating a Java Servlet application which requires a pool of database connections. I have implemented the `ConnectionPool` class as a `ServletContextListener`, overriding `contextInitialized` and `contextDestroyed`. I also declared it as a listener in the `web.xml`. Stack exchange did not allow me to post the code directly, saying it was too much code, so I have put pastebin links to my code.

When I deploy the web app, it does not start it. When I try to start it manually, the tomcat manager app is unable to do so. It gives me a generic error message. The log I have posted starts after deploying, but before manually starting.

[My catalina.out file](http://pastebin.com/6Rzg1eMS)
[My connection pool file](http://pastebin.com/8RMvtL1g)
[My `web.xml` file](http://pastebin.com/7skZXzKC)

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: I don't think everyone will able to open these attachments, even if they can, it is better to provide crisp details to get answers easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what went wrong. When I looked through my code, I realized I never initialized a variable that I was referencing. When I corrected that, my code ran smoothly. Moral of the story: Everyone makes mistakes; use exception handling on everything!